# Counting blank cells based on the information in a related cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use information from a table to display a count of blank cells based on the type of data in the table. See my example below - I want to count how many of each fruit I'm missing, regardless of their color, and ignoring the apples I do have.

Table:

[image]

End result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula will almost retrieve the table you want.

### Formula

```
 QUERY(data, query, headers)

=QUERY(
   DATA!A1:C7,                                         // data
   "SELECT A, COUNT(B) WHERE C IS NULL GROUP BY A      // query
      LABEL COUNT(B) 'Amount of Empty Types'"             
 )
```

### Explained

Column A is selected to be shown. It is not possible, with the `QUERY` formula, to perform on the same column a count and select operation. Therefore I performed the count on column B. The where clause on column C is set to contain nothing. All results are to be grouped by column A. At the end of the query, the header/label is changed (otherwise it would show "count Color".

### Result

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Counting blank cells based on information in related cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEJrOE9lcUJpRS10VG8wV19wc3NhRVE&usp=sharing)**

Comment: I was so close... That really cleared it up for me thanks so much.

Comment: I am getting a strange issue though. The Query works for every sheet except the First sheet. 

The query of my first sheet is returning all the data except the first 5 lines, and in the cell with the Query formula, it returns the first 4 lines from the Type column on the first sheet.

Comment: @Tom Why don't you add me to your file, so that I can have a look....